# Delete the file which contains a string in its name

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete a file if it contains a word. I could able to find file if it contains a specified word,

```
    Dim paths() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(%AppData% & "\etc\", "*chrome*")
    If paths.Length > 0 Then
   ' Delete file?
    End If
```

What is the correct way to delete the file ?

Comment: thats doesnt compile does it

Comment: That tells if there is a file contains the word. But unfortunately, I don't know how to delete it.

Comment: Please use directoryInfo not DirectoryInfo

Comment: VB is not case sensitive

Comment: Yes but in this case its trying to access static method of DirectoryInfo instead of instance method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should the job:

```
Dim path = IO.Path.Combine(
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
           "etc")

    Dim filter = "chrome"
    Dim files =
        From fl In IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
        Where fl.Contains(filter)
        Select fl

    For Each fl In files
        IO.File.Delete(fl)
    Next
```

Comment: +1 A bit overkill but at least it is different from the usual approach

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.
First you need to have [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx) and from there you need to search & delete.

```
      For Each file In New DirectoryInfo(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).GetFiles("*chrome*")
        file.Delete()
      Next
```